# Automatic page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am  using the following code -

```
jQuery(".form_" + form_count).html("<div id='message'></div>")
    jQuery('#message').html("<center><h2><br><br>Thank You Your form has been submitted.</h2></center>")
window.setTimeout(function() {
    history.go(-1);
}, 1950);
```

Now what i want is that after the previous page has been loaded using **history.go(-1)** that page should get refreshed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following function to refresh redirected page :

```
function refresh()
{
    window.location.reload( true );
}
```

Comment: i tried using what you said but that actually reloaded the page previous to the page i was redirecting using the history command. what i want is that the page i reached using history.go(-1) should be refreshed.  Please help..

Comment: for that you have to write this script on page you are going back

Answer (score -1):

Add the below meta tags in your previous page

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```