# How to auto refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099430/automatic-page-refresh)

I found this on and off switch online and would like to use it to refresh a page. If the user click the "on" it will refresh the page every 5 seconds. If they click off it will stop. Can some please help me out. Here's what I have so far:

```
<style>



body{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}

.left{
float:left;
width:120px;}

#ajax{
float:left;
width:300px;
padding-top:5px;
font-weight:700;
}

.clear{clear:both;}

</style>

</head>

<body>


</a></div>
<div id="container">


 <div class="left" id="1"></div>
 <div id="ajax"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#1').iphoneSwitch("on", 
     function() {
       $('#ajax').load('on.html');
      },
      function() {
       $('#ajax').load('off.html');
      },
      {
        switch_on_container_path: 'iphone_switch_container_off.png'
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: id cannot start with a number

Comment: @sushanthreddy - `id` CAN start with a number nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable and disable page refresh like this:

```
var refreshTimer;

$('#button').iphoneSwitch("on", 
    function() {
        refreshTimer = setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); }, 5000);
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout(refreshTimer);
    },
    {
        switch_on_container_path: 'iphone_switch_container_off.png'
    }
);
```

If you want to reload some html using ajax you can use something like this (using setInterval):

```
var refreshTimer;

function ajaxReload()
{
    $.ajax .. etc
}

$('#button').iphoneSwitch("on", 
    function() {
        refreshTimer = setInterval(ajaxReload, 5000);
    },
    function() {
        clearInterval(refreshTimer);
    },
    {
        switch_on_container_path: 'iphone_switch_container_off.png'
    }
);
```

**Edit**

In this example page reloading is disabled by default, when the users enables it using the button it will stay on untill disabled

```
var refreshTimer;

function enableTimer()
{
    refreshTimer = setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); }, 5000);
    window.location.hash = "#autoreload";
}

function disableTimer()
{
    clearTimeout(refreshTimer);
    window.location.hash = "";
}

$(function() {

    $('#button').iphoneSwitch(
        (window.location.hash == "#autoreload" ? "on" : "off"), 
        enableTimer, 
        disableTimer
    );

    if (window.location.hash == "#autoreload")
        enableTimer();
});
```

Comment: This only refresh the page one time, is there a way for it to keep refreshing until it's turned off. Whenever I click on the on switch it will refresh once.

Comment: I have updated my answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: Please be patient with me. This is where I downloaded the full script from: http://papermashup.com/jquery-iphone-style-ajax-switch/ . I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the whole button disappear when I try to add your code. Can you help me a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: I've been at it for couple hours, guess I'll take a break to get my head straight. Will try again tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for help.

Comment: There was an error in my code, it is working now. A full working example: [link](http://pastebin.com/GnBH1yqb)

Comment: The code works but I can't get it to work on internet explorer. May you do the same with this: https://github.com/tdreyno/iphone-style-checkboxes/blob/master/jquery-demo.html . Thats the only one that shows the button in ie. Thank you.

Comment: The test page I gave you works for me in Internet Explorer 8. Can you tell me what is not working for you?

Comment: The whole button dissapears in ie 8.

Comment: I got it, I'm sorry. It look like some other script was conflicting with that one. It's fix.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple timeout javascript function, such as:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var timeoutPeriod = 5000;
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
    }

</script>
```

You could add the logic to only run this when the on switch is clicked.

Comment: I got this script online , so can you explain just where exacly how I would put your code, and is it for the "on" or the "off" feature. Thanks.

Comment: You should really begin with learning what you are doing instead of just copy-pasting stuff you don't know how it works imho.

Comment: You are right but I have a deadline I got to meet and just really need help.